# Responsive image size on document loaded using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a custom carousel / slider element. And I've encountered a thing that just doesn't make sense.

When i try to get image size using jquery on document loaded it calculates the wrong width / height. I thought its a problem with document not being loaded once page shows. But that doesn't seems to be the case, because beside jquery document loaded function, I have even used https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded library.

Lucky thing I was playing with this on CodePen so here is the link: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ljiech/pen/jyONNG)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $(".carousel").imagesLoaded(function(){
  //shows logo before images are loaded
  $(".logo-container").addClass("hide");
  $(".carousel").removeClass("hide");



  //get carousel dimensions
  const carouselEl = $(".carousel");

  //image
  const imageEl = $("img.active");

  //get active dimensions
  const elWidth = imageEl.width();
  const elHeight = imageEl.height();

  console.log(elWidth,elHeight);

  //set carousel dimensions
  carouselEl.width(elWidth);
  carouselEl.height(elHeight);
  });

});
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `naturalHeight` property of images

Comment: Your JavaScript is correct, but the problem lies in the css fil

Answer (score 1):

Your css tells images to have `max-width:100vw;` 100% of the screen, so always have 1920px in my case.

you can ask the real image dimension.width by: `imageEl[0].naturalWidth`

#### explanation

`[0]` turns jquery object into a native javascript HtmlElement (Gets the first out of the selection)

Then you by simply taking the naturalWidth, naturalHeight and ViewportWidth you can define the desired height:

#### calculate desired height, based on screen width and image height/width ratio.

naturalWidth / naturalHeight = screen ration => should be equal to: viewPortWidth / desired height.

`viewPortWidth / naturalWidth * naturalHeight = desired (scaled) height`. based on width/height ratio.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but now on the same link I've added a click event on About which calls same function which resizes the container and it resizes it fine. So Im trying to understand why it isn't working on document loaded.

Comment: My research: it does work on most browsers except safari. They already fire the document ready event before all images are properly loaded, i gues they do this so they can say they are the fastest browser, or it is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.